# Using a BottomNavigationBar in Flutter, how can I set a background image, instead of using just a color?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to use an image for the BottomNavigationBar's background, but I didn't find anything yet. Any suggestion? The only attribute suggested is backgroundColor which requires a Color and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/img.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('title')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), title: Text('title')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the image's and it's Dimensional Details?